# How do I skip integration tests in Production envrionment?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I would like to skip integration tests in Production during maven CI/CD pipeline.

I am using following in my `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <groups>IntegrationTest</groups>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is there any configuration setting that will allow me to skip integration tests during CI/CD in Production?

Comment: What do you mean by "in production"? You don't build your application again for production, you build it, and test it, and then it goes to production (without any rebuild).